How can i reflect var changes to rememberSaveable on the screen?
I'm learning Jetpack Compose and I'm having a bit of a problem reflecting the changes of this var, "repeticiones" (repetitions):
var repeticiones by remember { mutableIntStateOf(3) }
The var is used like this:
Row(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(), horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.Center) {
                Text(
                    text = stringResource(R.string.repeticiones),
                    fontSize = 30.sp,
                    textAlign = TextAlign.Center
                )
                Spacer(modifier = Modifier.width(8.dp))
                Text(
                    text = repeticiones.toString(),
                    fontWeight = FontWeight.Bold,
                    fontSize = 40.sp,
                    textAlign = TextAlign.Center
                )
            }

The output on the screen would be something like this: "Repeticiones: N" where repetitions equals N. I give the var its real value in this block of code:
val person by workoutViewModel.person.observeAsState()
var repeticiones by remember {
        mutableIntStateOf(3)
    }
val coroutineScope = rememberCoroutineScope()
var parar by rememberSaveable {
       mutableStateOf(false)
    }

person?.let {data->
        name = data.name
        repeticiones = data.repeticiones
    }

The screen does indeed reflect the data from the ViewModel, but somehow it does not reflect the changes im trying to apply here:
var parar by rememberSaveable {
        mutableStateOf(false)
    }
Button(
                onClick = {
                    coroutineScope.launch {
                        while (repeticiones > 0) {
                            delay(200)
                            if (parar) {
                                break
                            }
                            workoutViewModel.restarRepeticion()
                        }
                    }
                }
            ) {
                Text(
                    text = stringResource(R.string.btn_comenzar)
                )
            }
Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(20.dp))
            Button(
                onClick = {
                    parar = true
                }
            ) {
                Text(
                    text = stringResource(R.string.btn_parar)
                )
            }

As you can see, the idea is to use two buttons. The first one would start a countdown, bringing repetitions to zero (the method workoutViewModel.restarRepeticion() just substracts 1 from the var), this countdown could only be stopped by the second one, which would set "parar" (stop) to true and would trigger the break condition in the first button. For some reason im not seeing any changes. Here's the full code in case there's something I have overlooked:
package com.example.workoutpila.ui.screens

import androidx.compose.foundation.Image
import androidx.compose.foundation.background
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Arrangement
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Column
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Row
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Spacer
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.fillMaxSize
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.fillMaxWidth
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.height
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.padding
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.size
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.width
import androidx.compose.material.icons.Icons
import androidx.compose.material.icons.filled.ArrowBack
import androidx.compose.material3.BottomAppBar
import androidx.compose.material3.Button
import androidx.compose.material3.Icon
import androidx.compose.material3.IconButton
import androidx.compose.material3.MaterialTheme
import androidx.compose.material3.Scaffold
import androidx.compose.material3.Text
import androidx.compose.runtime.Composable
import androidx.compose.runtime.getValue
import androidx.compose.runtime.livedata.observeAsState
import androidx.compose.runtime.saveable.rememberSaveable
import androidx.compose.ui.Alignment
import androidx.compose.ui.Modifier
import androidx.compose.ui.res.stringResource
import androidx.compose.ui.text.font.FontWeight
import androidx.compose.ui.text.style.TextAlign
import androidx.compose.ui.unit.dp
import androidx.compose.ui.unit.sp
import androidx.navigation.NavController
import com.example.workoutpila.viewmodel.WorkoutViewModel
import com.example.workoutpila.R
import androidx.compose.runtime.*
import androidx.compose.ui.res.painterResource
import com.example.workoutpila.navigation.Routes
import kotlinx.coroutines.delay
import kotlinx.coroutines.launch

@Composable
fun WorkoutScreen(navController: NavController, workoutViewModel: WorkoutViewModel){

    val person by workoutViewModel.person.observeAsState()
    var name by remember {
        mutableStateOf("Cargando...")
    }
    var repeticiones by remember {
        mutableIntStateOf(3)
    }
    val coroutineScope = rememberCoroutineScope()
    var parar by rememberSaveable {
        mutableStateOf(false)
    }

    person?.let {data->
        name = data.name
        repeticiones = data.repeticiones
    }
    Scaffold(
        bottomBar = {
            BottomAppBar(
                modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth()
            ) {
                IconButton(
                    onClick = {
                        navController.navigate(Routes.MainScreen.route)
                    },
                    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth()
                ) {
                    Row(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth()) {
                        Icon(imageVector = Icons.Default.ArrowBack, contentDescription = "Back")
                        Spacer(modifier = Modifier.width(20.dp))
                        Text(text = stringResource(R.string.btn_volver))
                    }
                }
            }
        }

    ) {
        Column(
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxSize()
                .padding(it)
                .background(MaterialTheme.colorScheme.background),
            verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center,
            horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally
        ) {
            Row(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .fillMaxWidth()
                    .padding(10.dp)
            ) {
                Text(
                    text = stringResource(R.string.frase_workout) + " $name",
                    fontWeight = FontWeight.Bold,
                    fontSize = 40.sp,
                    textAlign = TextAlign.Center
                )


            }
            Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(40.dp))
            Row(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(), horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.Center) {
                Text(
                    text = stringResource(R.string.repeticiones),
                    fontSize = 30.sp,
                    textAlign = TextAlign.Center
                )
                Spacer(modifier = Modifier.width(8.dp))
                Text(
                    text = repeticiones.toString(),
                    fontWeight = FontWeight.Bold,
                    fontSize = 40.sp,
                    textAlign = TextAlign.Center
                )
            }
            Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(20.dp))
            Image(
                painter = painterResource(R.drawable.workout_img),
                contentDescription = "Workout",
                modifier = Modifier.size(300.dp)
            )
            Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(20.dp))
            Button(
                onClick = {
                    coroutineScope.launch {
                        while (repeticiones > 0) {
                            delay(200)
                            if (parar) {
                                break
                            }
                            workoutViewModel.restarRepeticion()
                        }
                    }
                }
            ) {
                Text(
                    text = stringResource(R.string.btn_comenzar)
                )
            }
            Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(20.dp))
            Button(
                onClick = {
                    parar = true
                }
            ) {
                Text(
                    text = stringResource(R.string.btn_parar)
                )
            }
        }
    }
}

Thank you for your time.
I have even tried without coroutine to check if that was the issue:
onClick = {
                    workoutViewModel.restarRepeticion()
                }

But it still doesn't reflect on the screen. Here's the viewmodel code:
import androidx.lifecycle.LiveData
import androidx.lifecycle.MutableLiveData
import com.example.workoutpila.model.WorkoutData
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModel
import androidx.lifecycle.viewModelScope
import kotlinx.coroutines.launch

class WorkoutViewModel: ViewModel() {
    private val _person = MutableLiveData<WorkoutData>()
    val person: LiveData<WorkoutData> = _person

    init {
        // Corrutina: coroutineScope
        viewModelScope.launch {
            _person.value = WorkoutData.getData()
        }
    }

    fun setRepeticiones(repeticiones:Int){
        val currentData = _person.value
        if(currentData!=null){
            val updatedData=WorkoutData(currentData.name, repeticiones)
            _person.value=updatedData
        }
    }

    fun setNombre(name:String){
        val currentData = _person.value
        if(currentData!=null){
            val updatedData=WorkoutData(name, currentData.repeticiones)
            _person.value=updatedData
        }
    }

    fun restarRepeticion(){
        val currentData = _person.value
        if(currentData!=null){
            val updatedData=WorkoutData(currentData.name, currentData.repeticiones--)
            _person.value=updatedData
        }
    }
}


"workoutViewModel.restarRepeticion() just substracts 1": Are you sure? Please [edit] your question and add that function as well.

Your view model's restarRepeticion is the culprit. Let's assume the person's repeticiones is 3. This is what happens:

currentData.repeticiones is 3.
currentData.repeticiones-- returns 3 (not what you want!) and then decrements it so currentData.repeticiones is now 2 because that's how the -- operator works.
A new WorkoutData object is assigned for the value of the LiveData, constructed with the return value of currentData.repeticiones--, that is 3 (not what you want!).
In your compose code the LiveData's observer registers the change and updates the person State. Since the new object is equal to the old object (their properties are the same) the Compose runtime ignores that change and in consequence no recomposition is triggered. Even if there was a recomposition the UI would still display the same because person.repeticiones is still 3.

What you want to do is use currentData.repeticiones - 1 instead of currentData.repeticiones--. It can also be expressed a little bit more concise like this:
_person.value = currentData.copy(repeticiones = currentData.repeticiones - 1)


All of this could have been avoided from the start if you had made WorkoutData immutable by declaring all properties as val (which is the general recommendation for anything that holds a state). The -- operator cannot be applied to an immutable variable so the compiler would have prevented you from using it in the first place.

Because that's how the -- operator works - It rather is how the postfix -- operator works. The prefix -- would have given the OP the behavior they had expected.

One might think so, but what actually would have happened is that the LiveData's previous content (currentData.repeticiones) is modified to be equal to the new value of the LiveData. In consequence the observeAsState() won't register that as a state change and the UI won't be updated although the LiveData has the correct value. The next time, however, the state will be updated. This alternates, so in effect every odd LiveData change will be skipped. The reason for this behavior is that Compose expects state objects to be immutable which is not the case here.
